# Why does only the first comment with `/*!` get preserved and none of the others?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I thought all comments with `/*!` would be preserved in the compiled javascript. However, it appears that only the first one is for some reason.

```
/*!
 * tsfile.ts
 * - a demonstrative typescript file 
 * - to compile: `./node_modules/.bin/tsc tsfile.ts`
 * 
 * Copyright © Grateful | Fri Oct 09
 */


// Number
let num: number = 0.444;
let hex: number = 0xbeef;
let bin: number = 0b0010;

/*
 * tsfile2.ts
 * - a demonstrative typescript file 
 * - to compile: `./node_modules/.bin/tsc tsfile.ts`
 * 
 * Copyright © Grateful | Fri Oct 09
 */


// Number
let num2: number = 0.444;
let hex2: number = 0xbeef;
let bin2: number = 0b0010;

/*! 
 * Another comment that should be preserved! 
 */

// Number
let num3: number = 0.444;
let hex3: number = 0xbeef;
let bin3: number = 0b0010;


// 1. any
// 2. built-in ie number, string, boolean, undefined, null, void, etc
// 3. user-defined ie array, enum, array, class, interface, and tuple


// Number
let num4: number = 0.444;
let hex4: number = 0xbeef;
let bin4: number = 0b0010;
```

Here is an [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?removeComments=true#code/PQKghAUABCUC4GcBmBLANgUwHSOrAtFAIZQAmGAtgPYB2CcATkXCgG4bwCeADhggMYMU3OFFSYoeKIThUo-KhW7oMALigADLMBpVyAfWqkArpgTAsAIxQ1gifvGQqcCDVKkBhKt05CA5gAWogCVUADiTHAYSKZQAD5QAGJCUADy-KIADACceMAQBcDAUAByxhSWGAwQmKI05er1FVVQALxQmVgALD0A3DUYogEYAB6N5ZUMbR0jldH9tVDWNOPNU+2ZlpmZAIyZ-RCgUojiGABMLlKEJOTUdIzMbBxwPHyCwqKnkjDS8HIKShU6i0Oj0GEMelMfAsyzsAkcpxcbh+nm8vhQgRC4Ui0ViCWSKDSGQ6uRg+UKxTKawGdXKZ1Wk2mnR6XQWgygwxG9KgTUZG1mGHmNKWNm5vJaGy2u32hXA31gABVXgBld4iLi8BDy8lFUoTKrCpoAZgZEo63T6ws5Jp5+vWMzmSDZomWNvF9s22z2B0OxR2WGINE4vqgFyWxnQcHwNigKA47oANFB6EIaH4k5YqFRMEQaEnjDRyKgaBhSEn6mg0EnWFQUGWoIN+CGjQHjAgqvgizZS7GOEQGExOEmME0k-3B0n+GgiAgEEmbFEGEgiPwMGPC-BjNxMAUQ1TJobyl1TR6LayraNj7a1kyBULFssr+6mVLvUA).

Comment: You are using the `removeComments` option which explains why they are being removed. It looks like, that if a comment is the first thing, then it is preserved. Not sure why that is the case yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `removeComments` option which, according to [the documentation:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

> Remove all comments except **copy-right header comments** beginning with /*!

(Emphasis mine).

So it looks like comments need to be both in the header (ie. no code before them) and be `/*!` to be preserved.

If you want to preserve all comments, just turn the `removeComments` option off.

Comment: Ooh! That is tight!! How would I pick and choose various comments?

Comment: So you mean you want to preserve certain kinds of comments, and not others? 

I would look at using a babel plugin for that.

Comment: No, I am not speaking about the various comment types. I am just interested in being able to preserve the ones that I would like to keep and remove the others.

Comment: @Grateful So you want to keep ones with `/*!` and get rid of the others? I would look at using a babel plugin for that. Could look at this: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#shouldprintcomment  But to be honest, I would just consider keeping all comments.

Comment: @Grateful I see someone else wants to do what you want here: https://github.com/babel/minify/issues/961

Comment: Interesting. Thank you very much for looking into this.